# Peut-on « laisser quelque chose à quelqu'un pour faire … » ?

Tags: grammaire, constructions-causatives

Je voudrais savoir si cette structure est correcte:

> laisser quelque chose à quelqu'un pour [verbe à l'infinitif].

Exemple: *laisse les églises aux fidèles pour fréquenter/visiter.*

Comment: C'est grammaticalement correct, quoiqu'un un peu lourd. De plus, si on dit "Maxime a laissé son livre à son frère pour travailler", on ne saura pas si c'est Maxime ou son frère qui va travailler. C'est pourquoi il est préférable d'éviter cette formulation, donc ce sera plutôt: "Maxime a laissé son livre à son frère pour qu'il puisse travailler".

Comment: Je suis d'accord que c'est pas clair qui va travailler avec "pour travailler", mais cette ambiguité peut exister avec "pour qu'il puisse travailler" aussi, non? @Graffito

Comment: Je ne sais pas si l'ajoute d'un pronom entre 'pour' et l'infinitif est permis par votre question, mais j'ai vu "je laisse une rente a mes enfants non mariés pour **en** profiter chacun par part egale" (ou, en rigolant, "pour **les** convaincre de rester celibitaires") dans les contextes testimentaires. (pardon my French, please)

Comment: @PapaPoule - Le pronom "Il" se réfère au dernier nom avec lequel il peut s'accorder, soit son frère. Cela me semble une règle générale en Français.

Comment: @Graffito Je n'ai personnellement jamais entendu cette règle, et quoi qu'il en soit, on dirait également "Maxime a laissé son livre à son frère pour qu'il puisse travailler" si Maxime a besoin d'avoir les mains libres, et où c'est donc Maxime qui pourra travailler. Ce qui implique une ambiguïté qu'il faut éviter. Il faut donc rajouter du contexte pour ne laisser aucune ambiguïté (si on sait qui veut travailler, on sait quel est le sujet).

Comment: @PapaPoule - "en" n'est pas approprié pour se référer aux enfants: ce pronom est le complément indirect du verbe (on profite de quelquechose) et non le sujet.

Comment: @Graffito "pour profiter de la rente chacun par part egale "....I think the "en" in such last wills/testaments refers to the rent. i didn't interpret the question to mean the "verbs a l'infinitif"couldn't have an indirect object....well in fact I did say here are some examples just in case "en" and "les" can come between "pour" and the infinitive.

Comment: @PapaPoule - Yes, "en" refers to the rent. (*Les enfants profiteront de la rente*). However, if you say in French " je fais quequechose pour en profiter", it is clear that the benefit is for you. In other cases, you will use "pour que *subject_pronoun verb*". So your sentence should be "Je laisse une rente à mes enfants non mariés pour qu'ils en profitent chacun à part égale".

Comment: @Graffito Thanks! So I’ll change the wills accordingly, but does this mean that my wife, une de ces enseignantes qui “laissent du temps aux enfants pour développer leurs idées et leurs réponses” should change her lesson plans to the subjunctive, too?

Comment: @PapaPoule - The use of the subjonctive is in many cases optional. Opposite to indicative that refers to real facts, the subjonctive denotes some doubt related to a possibility or a probability to occur. [wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subjonctif).

Answer (score 2):

*Ne pouvant répondre complètement à @Random, dans un "comment", j'ai fait cette réponse pour indiquer la règle:*

> Lorsque le pronom personnel anaphorique reprend un terme, celui-ci
>   doit être clairement identifiable dans le texte. Pour cela il est
>   établi que le pronom doit être du même genre et du même nombre que
>   l'antécédent (*le nom*).
>
> Cette règle bien qu'étant essentielle pour repérer l'antécédent, n'est
>   pas toujours suffisante pour lever l'ambigüité. En effet, le choix du
>   bon référent n'était pas toujours évident pour le lecteur si il
>   y a dans l'énoncé plusieurs termes dont les marques morphologiques
>   de genre et de nombre sont identiques à celles du pronom représentant.
>
> Avant le XVIIe siècle, il n'y avait pas de lois qui permettaient dans
>   ce cas de désigner clairement le bon référent. Ce qui fait que dans
>   les textes anciens, on peut remarquer des constructions où il manquait
>   de précision pour trouver le mot qui sert d'antécédent au pronom.
>
> Au XVIIe siècle, les remarqueurs, comme Vaugelas, le père Bouhours et
>   Andry de Bois -Regard, vont alors s'appliquer à **éviter toute
>   ambiguïté**. Ils établissent des règles qui permettent au lecteur
>   d'interpréter facilement le pronom. Ces règles reposent sur deux
>   critères qui facilitent la relation de transparence entre le pronom et
>   l'antécédent.
>
> - Le premier critère est celui de la **proximité** entre les deux termes (*nom et pronom*)
> - Le second est en rapport avec la cohérence du texte : deux pronoms personnels identiques qui se suivent, doivent nécessairement avoir le
>     même antécédent.

[Source](http://www.memoireonline.com/10/08/1601/m_pronom-personnel-troisieme-personne-place-reference-francais-classique-moderne5.html)

Answer (score 1):

"laisser quelque chose à quelqu'un pour [verbe à l'infinitif]".
can be correct (like the exemple of the book given above).
laisser une chaise pour s'assoir (i.e. anybody).
but "laisser une chaise pour qu'il puisse s'assoir" (i.e. somebody known).

"laisse les églises aux fidèles pour fréquenter/visiter" is not.
(I'm not even sure what is the target meaning).
laisser les églises aux fidèles pour qu'ils puissent les fréquenter/visiter ?
laisser les fidèles fréquenter/visiter les églises ? (not exactly the same shade).

Answer (score 1):

La tournure est **correcte**:

> laisser quelque chose à quelqu'un pour [verbe à l'infinitif].

Cela signifie que l'action (*forme à l'infinitif*) va employer *quelque chose* comme **complément de moyen**:

> avec/au moyen de quelque chose  (avec une casserole)

La tournure *laisser les églises aux fidèles pour fréquenter/visiter* est **incorrecte**

car fréquenter/visiter est un verbe transitif qui nécessite un COD, qui est *les églises*, et doit être représenté par un **pronom** (les)

> Il faut utiliser => pour **les** fréquenter/visiter

En effet, on ne pourrait pas dire je fréquente avec les églises.

L'autre tournure est donc:

> laisser quelque chose à quelqu'un pour le/la/les [verbe **transitif** à l'infinitif sans COD].

Avec des verbes intransitifs, c'est le pronom correspondant:

> parler de cette histoire => laisser cette histoire à quelqu'un **pour en** parler.
>
> grimper à la corde => laisser cette corde à quelqu'un **pour y** grimper.
>
> grimper sur cette chaise => laisser cette chaise à quelqu'un **pour** grimper **dessus**.

On peut bien sûr avoir:

> laisser quelque chose à quelqu'un pour [verbe **transitif** à l'infinitif avec COD].
>
> Laisser la casserole à quelqu'un pour cuire le steak.
>
> laisser quelque chose à quelqu'un pour [verbe **intransitif** à l'infinitif avec COI].
>
> Laisser la rente à ses enfant pour en profiter.

**Enfin, il faut éviter les ambiguités:**

Pour + infinitif se réfère normalement au sujet de la principale. Avec *laisser*, il paraît clair que le sujet devient *quelqu'un* (COI du verbe *laisser à*)

**En cas de doute, la tournure (un peu lourde) est :**

> *pour que* + forme au subjonctif: pour qu'il grimpe dessus.